# Finding the Lowest ID Based On the Status Of Another Column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, min

There are a lot of tips on the use of the MIN() function, but the situation below is more complicated because of multiple conditions.  Each [Project] can have multiple [Work Order]s and each [Work Order] can have multiple [Op Seq ID]s.

***TABLE: WorkOrders***

| Project | Work Order | Op Seq ID | Op Status Code | Op Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 10 | Complete | Saw |
| A | 100 | 20 | Complete | Weld |
| A | 100 | 30 | NULL | Paint |
| A | 100 | 40 | NULL | Label |
| A | 101 | 10 | Complete | Laser |
| A | 101 | 20 | NULL | Drill |
| A | 101 | 30 | NULL | Paint |
| B | 115 | 10 | NULL | Laser |
| B | 115 | 20 | NULL | Drill |

Within each [Project], I am looking to return each [Work Order] with the LOWEST [Op Seq ID] WHERE [Op Status Code] = NULL.

| Project | Work Order | Op Seq ID | Op Status Code | Op Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 30 | NULL | Paint |
| A | 101 | 20 | NULL | Drill |
| B | 115 | 10 | NULL | Laser |

I started down the pathway with the following query, but got stuck trying to find the lowest Op Seq ID with an Op Status Code of NULL for each Work Order.

```
SELECT [WO Project ID], [Op Seq ID]
FROM dbo.WorkOrders T1
WHERE [WO Project ID] =
    (SELECT MIN([Op Seq ID]) 
    FROM dbo.WorkOrders T2
    WHERE T1.[WO Project ID] = T2.[WO Project ID])
```

Answer (score 0):

A community member pointed me to another similar post; with some editing the following query returns the correct results:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Work Order ID] ORDER BY [Op Seq ID] ASC) AS rn
    FROM dbo.WorkOrders
    WHERE [Op Status Code] IS NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```